# Flask issues with encoding when parsing pdf as text

Tags: python, flask, pdf, text, encoding

I have a function which parses pdf as text:

```
def convert_pdf_to_text(pdf_path):
    """Convert a PDF file to text."""
    try:
        with fitz.open(pdf_path) as doc:
            text = ""
            for page in doc:
                # Assuming get_text() returns a Unicode string
                page_text = page.get_text()
                # Encode to UTF-8 and then decode back to ensure it's a UTF-8 string
                text += page_text.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
            return text
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {pdf_path}: {e}")
        return None
```

It works perfectly fine in python 3.11, but not flask, returns error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1493-1498: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am working with text and equations, and the function parses everything legibly in python but not in flask.

I've tried explicitly using utf 8 encoding, as well as encoding the text after it is returned in flask. It allows the text to be printed, but equations are replaced with these symbols:

`\x91\x91 \xf0\x9d`

If it helps, I need to parse pdf as text to prompt openai. I won't be using vectorstores.

Comment: you can try `latin-1` . It seen some character cannot decode by utf-8

Comment: @KJ how do you suggest I fix this then? And how come python is fine but flask is not?